# migration from vs 2005 to 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

just migrated my development teams on to vs 2008.  can anyone give there biggest highlights of this upgrade on useful features.

EDIT: we are still doing winforms development

Comment: I find it funny, but kind of sad that you've just migrated to 2008 and 2010 is just around the corner. The beta is awesome, so far.

Comment: I find it funny that you migrated to vs2008 without any clear reason why it would be better.

Comment: we figured it had to have at least 3 years of bug fixes from 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you use in Visual Studio - but a good place to start looking for things to highlight might be [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx).

- If you work in C# or Visual Basic, [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) is a pretty big deal.
- In C# being able to use [implict typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) for local variables is great.
- C# 3.0's [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) are also really neat.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPF, the XAML editor is quite a bit better.